# Triggering a UI message based on a terminal ssh'd to another server

Tags: command-line, ssh, notification

I am working in a multi-workspace multi-window configuration. I am constantly running scripts behind the scenes.

It would save me a lot of time and context switching if I could kick off a script on another server and have a message popup (growl notify or w/e) on my desktop letting me know that the command finished.

Is there a way to do that in Ubuntu 10?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it, assuming you have password-less SSH set up:

```
ssh my-graphical-workstation 'env DISPLAY=$(w -s $USER | grep -m 1 " :" | awk "{print \$3}") notify-send "Done processing."'
```

You'll need [libnotify-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/libnotify-bin) [image: Install libnotify-bin] installed on `my-graphical-workstation`.

Adjust it as necessary.

Comment: Why not simply use `ssh server command && notify-send "Done processing."`, run (of course) from the workstation where the notification should go?

Comment: @loevborg This can be integrated into scripts that reside on the remote machine, does not require the SSH connection to be maintained while the job is processing, and is convenient to use from within GNU Screen.

Comment: this sounds great! Except I am not getting popups. Libnotify is of course installed.  I rummaged in my system settings to try and get an event source configured, but I didn't see any "notify-send" or "read stuff from CLI" source.

Comment: @Paul To troubleshoot, first confirm that notifications appear when you run just `notify-send "Done processing."` on the graphical workstation. Then, on the remote machine, check what happens if you use `echo env` in place of `env` in the full SSH command. You should see output that's similar to `env DISPLAY=:0.0 notify-send Done processing.` Confirm that the value of `DISPLAY` in that output matches one of the values in the `FROM` column of `w -s` on the graphical workstation.

Comment: Yeah, my workstation doesn't show it. :-/

Comment: @ændrük: any idea why `notify-send` might not be working? (Better post a new question, else?)

Answer (score 0):

To augment the fine answer by @ændrük:

you might need to allow the connection from the remote machine. At the simplest, use

```
xhost +
```

but you *should* restrict this to the target machine once working, if you do not want the whole world to open X11 windows on your machine. This is done automatically if you do `ssh -X`, but needs to be added manually if the ssh connection is not maintained.

If you are always connected, just add a `-X` to your ssh parameter to have it do the setup for you, as in

```
user@localhost:path$ ssh -X where_the_script_is_run
user@where_the_script_is_run:path$ run-script; xmessage 'whatever message'
```

`notify-send` did not work for me remotely. You can use the (archaic) `xmessage` program.